# remove or turn off the option to "disable network connection" in windows

Tags: windows, networking

working in the Network Connections window its all too easy to right click and disable the network connection.

When this is done through a remote session its particularly annoying as physical location can mean its a problem to get it enabled again.

Is there a setting that can remove the "disable" option from the right click options on the network adaptor or a group policy that can prevent users from disabling the NIC in windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by implementing a Group Policy Object.

See http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/prevent-users-from-disabling-network-connections-in-windows-server-2008/3819